# Connecting to Wordpress Database

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a problem with my custom theme for wordpress. I made a custom theme locally on my PC where I installed Wordpress. Now inside my theme is another folder let's say **php**, and inside this folder is a php file that will fetch data from the database which I want to run later on. The code in this php file is as follows:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('/wp-blog-header.php');
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
global $wpdb;
$rs = $wpdb->get_results("select * from wp_users"); 
$user_db=$rs[0]->user_nicename;
echo $user_db;
?>
```

The codes above works on my local machine, where it prints out the user_nicename field from my local database (phpMyAdmin). Now when I upload and install the custom theme I made and access this php file the browser displays nothing. Is something missing in define or require so I can successfully connect to the Wordpress database? Any help help would be much appreciated.
Please note that theme is located at **C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\custom_theme** and the php file to connect to database is here: **C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\custom_theme\php\connect.php**

Comment: `user_nickname`, not user_nicename :) right?

Comment: yes it's correct. let's just say that **user_nicename** is a field in the database. :)

Comment: Can you add this to your header.php `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, with errors switched on you will find the error much quicker.

Comment: which header.php file? the header.php inside my theme folder? or the wp-blog-header.php?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the above code, why not just the function get_userdata on your template where you want to display the user nicename.

```
<?php 
    $user = get_userdata( $userid ); 
    echo $user->user_nicename;
?>
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata for details and look at the "Related" section at the bottom for other related uses.

Comment: the problem is I am not going to fetch just that user data but as well as other data from other database tables..

Comment: So, just fetch your other data separately. Either that, or, open up your functions.php file and create a custom function in there to pull your data to store in an object and then return the object.